# How to remove recent files in Export Wizard

Tags: export, oracle-sqldeveloper, recent-file-list

Using SQL Developer 4.1.3 (old version used due to compatibility with older Oracle instances) i found no way to delete entries from the recent files in the Export Wizard.
As this is quite annoying when the list grows large (also according to forum on thatjeffsmith.com - large list makes Export Wizard startup slower).
Where is the recent file list stored and how to sanitize it?

Answer (score 0):

The entries are stored in "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.1.3.20.78\o.sqldeveloper.12.2.0.20.78\product-preferences.xml"
in entry:

```
<hash n="DBConfig">
    <hash n="URLFileChooserPaths">
             <list n="DEFAULT_CONTEXT">
```